# Div Changes in HTML

Tags: ajax, html, swap

I m having one requirement of swaping div on html.Consider first div with id='current',on page load 5 records are append on first div.I do have one another div with id="next" which gets another 5 record filled after click event from ajax in innerhtml from javascript.Again after click event another 5 records picked,i want to append it on div with id='next' and next will go to current and old 5 records which is on current get empty from javascript and so on.For example:

```
<div id="current"></div>(current 5 records on pageload)
<div id="next"></div>(another 5 records on click event from ajax in innerHTML)
```

Again when onclick another 5 records are coming which I want to append on next and old next will go to current and old current get deleted.
Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: <div id="prev"></div><div id="content"></div><div id="next"></div>, is it using id='content' to display your data as a better way ??

Comment: Can you say which javascript library you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<div id="current">(current 5 records on pageload)</div>
<div id="next">(another 5 records on click event from ajax in innerHTML) </div>
<button id="loadDiv">Load Data</button>
```

**jquery**

```
var count = 1; // gobal variable for checking click count

$('#loadDiv').click(function(){

      data = // do ajax and get data
      if(count == 1)
      {
        $('#current').empty();  // deleting old data of current
        $('#current').html('data');
      }
      else   
      {
        $('#current').empty(); // deleting old data of current
        $('#current').html($('#next').html());// loading current with next
        $('#next').empty();  // deleting data in next
        $('#next').html(data); // loading next with new data
      }  
     count ++;       
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but in terms of javascript:                               document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=document.getElementById("next").innerHTML; its not working.

Comment: @user3406754 `var content = document.getElementById("next").inn‌​erHTML; document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = content;` try like this

Comment: you dont have to use empty each time , html(new data) is just enough

Answer (score 0):

using jquery this is very easy:

```
<div id="current"></div>
<div id="next"></div>
```

in the ajax success function

```
$("#current").html($("#next").html())
$("#next").html(loaded_data)
```

Comment: the old records of current should get delete is that possible.

Comment: it got deleted already , teh html command will override old data .

Answer (score 0):

Just try that fucntions to do that. Functions not use jquery and do the same in diferent way.

1- Change content while new content is on a String.

```
function spaw_div_content(new_content){
    var current = document.getElementById("current")
    var next = document.getElementById("next")    
    current.innerHTML = next.innerHTML
    next.innerHTML = new_content;
}
```

2- Change content while new content is on an array of elements.

```
function spaw_div_content(new_content){
    var current = document.getElementById("current")
    var next = document.getElementById("next")

    current.innerHTML = next.innerHTML
    next.innerHTML = "";

    for(iNC in new_content){
        next.appendChild(new_content[iNC])
    }
}
```